# Using SSH Bash Script to send a PHP mail including the content of a log file

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I used this command before:

```
mail -s "Logs" "example@example.com" < /srv/users/log/php7.4.error.log
```

to send the content of the error log file to my email address.

Now I am on another server and cannot use `mail` anymore, but found PHP as alternative:

```
php -r 'mail("example@example.com", "Logs", "Content", "From:my@epicserver.xyz");'
```

How can I use the bash (mail.sh file) to not sent "Content" but the content of `/srv/users/log/php7.4.error.log` instead?

Can I declare a variable? And then insert a $content var inside the bash script?

In the shell script I tried:

```
LOGFILE = /srv/users/log/php7.4.error.log; 
php -r 'mail("example@example.com", "Logs", $LOGFILE, "From:my@epicserver.xyz");';
```

without success. Error is: "Warning: Undefined variable $LOGFILE in Command line code on line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the file content as a variable and use it as an argument

```bash
my_log=$(cat /srv/users/log/php7.4.error.log)
php -r "mail('example@example.com', '$my_log', 'Content', 'From:my@epicserver.xyz');"
```

This can also be written as

```bash
php -r "mail('example@example.com', '$(cat /srv/users/log/php7.4.error.log)', 'Content', 'From:my@epicserver.xyz');"
```

You can also use proper open/read PHP functions and only pass the file name from bash

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
file_name="$1"

php -r "
$myfile = fopen('$file_name', 'r') or die('Unable to open file!');
mail ... // consume php myfile variable;"
```

Keep in mind, you need to substitute bash variable in single/double quotes and do add proper escape characters if needed